# How to export complex JSON into .xlsx in React

Tags: reactjs, json, xlsx

So I'm trying to export complex JSON into .xlsx file. But the products data won't showing in the .xlsx file because the data is object.

This is my data

```js
const stockOpnameData = [
{ 
  id: 1, 
  products: [
              {id: '1a', name: 'product_1'}, 
              {id: '1b', name: 'product_2'}, 
              {id: '1c', name: 'product_3'}
            ], 
  description: 'testing'
}, 
{ 
  id: 2, 
  products: [
              {id: '2a', name: 'product_1'}, 
              {id: '2b', name: 'product_2'}, 
              {id: '2c', name: 'product_3'}
            ], 
  description: 'testing second'
}, 

//Many data here structured the same way as above
]
```

This is my functioin

```js
import * as FileSaver from 'file-saver'
import * as XLSX from 'xlsx'

const fileType = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;charset=UTF-8'
const fileExtension = '.xlsx'

export const exportToExcel = (csvData: any[], fileName: string) => {
  const ws = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(csvData)
  const wb = { Sheets: { data: ws }, SheetNames: ['data'] }
  
  const excelBuffer = XLSX.write(wb, { bookType: 'xlsx', type: 'array' })
  const data = new Blob([excelBuffer], { type: fileType })

  FileSaver.saveAs(data, fileName + fileExtension)
}
```

I want the products data is showing in the xlsx cells and I don't want move or split the products data into another table.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want a flat structure like

| id | product id | product name | description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1a | product_1 | testing |
| 1 | 1b | product_2 | testing |
| ... |  |  |  |

You could un-nest the data like this

```js
const csvData = stockOpnameData.flatMap(({ id, products, description }) =>
  products.map((p) => ({
    id,
    "product id": p.id,
    "product name": p.name,
    description,
  })),
);
```

Comment: thank you, this is works. but actually my expected result is

```
| id | product id |       product name                         | description      |
| 1  | 1a,1b,1c     | product_1, product_2, product_3 | testing             |
| 2  | 2a, 2b, 2c   | product_1, product_2, product_3 | testing second |
```